# Showing array data in nativescript-vue view modal component

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to create a modal component from the parent and fill data in that modal in a listview

If the component was already  created, I don't have a problem, but I want the component created in that parent page

```
template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Modal Data" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="m-20">
                <Button text="Button" @tap="goToDetailPage" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    const Detail = {
        template: `
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Asal Ikan" />
        <StackLayout>

            <ListView class="list-group" for="mylist in mylists" style="height:600px;">
                <v-template>
                <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">

                    <Label :text="mylist.name" style="width:100%;" @tap="closeModal" />

                </FlexboxLayout>
            </v-template>
            </ListView>



        </StackLayout>
     </Page>
        `
    };
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                mylists: [{
                        code: "SL",
                        name: "Sinjai"
                    },
                    {
                        code: "MK",
                        name: "Makasar"
                    }
                ]
            };
        },
        methods: {

            goToDetailPage() {
                this.$showModal(Detail);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Data from my List is not showing. 
here the playground link :
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=WlzgRU&v=104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things you may want to improve / correct in your code.

1. `Detail` is a standalone component, it won't have access to the data in your `Master` (HelloWorld) component. You should pass `mylists` in `props` if you like to access the same data.
2. A `Page` can only be hosted within a `Frame` and a valid `Page` can only have `ActionBar`. Since you haven't defined a `Frame` in your `Detail` component, it won't be valid.
3. With ListView use `itemTap` event instead of adding event listeners to individual component.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=WlzgRU&v=106)